# Best RWD method

Tags: html, css

What will be the best way of creating a responsive web design

```
1.bootstrap
2.w3
```

or any other method?????

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please check out the help center to see what topics you can ask about. Opinion based questions are off topic.

Comment: w3.css (a responsive web design method)

Comment: this question is only going to get you people's opinions. They both work. Look into their coding and use what you think will be easiest for you to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use bootstrap.
.    www.w3schools.com
You will find this website useful.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap would be better because it has more cross browser compatibility. Also Bootstrap v4 is coming which has a lot of new features. You can check here [Bootstrap v4](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/)